# How to copy Charts from one excel Sheet to another sheet using Apache POI Java?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I tried both ways using HSSFWorkbook and XSSFWorkbook but seems POI have some constraint over chart clone, getting below error as :

> Exception in thread "main" org.apache.poi.util.RecordFormatException:
>   java.lang.CloneNotSup

Comment: Could you provide a code sample or describe this case in more detail? For now it looks too generic and abstract.

Comment: I have one template which was given by client and it contains Charts, graph bars. 
1. I need to create Sheet which should have exact replica of client template
2. Similarly in similar sheet based on data manipulation i need to create multiple sheet which should have similar template style in all sheet.

Issue : 
1. I can directy copy as is Template in another Excel using File and HSSFWorkbook class of Api
2. Now, when i try to Copy or clone similar sheet and try to clone/copy it gives error as org.apache.poi.util.RecordFormatException

Comment: Could it be, that sheets you call 'similar' are not identical? What is the difference between them? Maybe the root cause is in differences between these files?

Comment: There is no such difference, only thing is i have one template of excel (say abc.xls) which contain Charts, barGraphs and Some Tables. 
Other excel is new(say xyz.xls) and Empty, I simply need to create new Excel i.e. xyz.xls with multiple Sheets inside it having same Template as abc.xls

Comment: 1. I am able to create Sheet using below snippets :

File myFile = new File("C:\\data\\Master.xls");
   FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(myFile);

   Workbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(fis);
   FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("test.xls"));

   wb.write(out);
   out.close();

2. I am facing problem in creating Multiple Sheets with similar Data in single Excel